# Load JSON data in Listview jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, listview, jquery-mobile

I am loading JSON data from data.json file in my root folder. I am using jQuery mobile the data I try and load works fine but not displaying in the proper Jquery mobile listview.

HTML Below

```
        <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.2/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.2/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Insert Page Title Here</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" id="view" >
    <p>Insert Content Here</p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Insert Footer Text Here</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

JS SCRIPT below

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function listPosts(data) {
    var output = '<form class="ui-filterable"><input id="searchposts" data-type="search"></form>';

    output += '<ul data-role="listview" >';
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {


        output += '<li>';
        output += '<a href="#post" onclick = "showPost(' + val.id + ')"></a>';
        output += '<h2>'+ val.name +'</h2>';
        output += '<img src="images/'+ val.shortname +'_tn.jpg" alt="'+ val.name +'" />';
        output += '<p>'+ val.bio +'</p>';
        output += '</li>';
    });
    output += '</ul>';
    $('#view').html(output);
}); //get JSON
```

My html output -

http://postimg.org/image/as1xjnu6l/

Any help ?

Thank you

Comment: onclick = "showPost( why the space ?

Comment: `$('#view').html(output).listview("refresh");`